# Foursquare userless endpoint asks for credentials

Tags: windows-phone-8, foursquare

I'm trying to access venue menu in venues endpoint of foursquare API through:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3/menu&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&v=20150115
```

But it is returning me an error:

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}
```

Although foursquare documentation says:

[image: Foursquare documentation]

please help.

Comment: Have you tried with another venue? The following may be the issue: "Not all menu information available on Foursquare is able to be redistributed through our API".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer. Its simple I was missing a query `?`parameter.

The URL should be:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/40a55d80f964a52020f31ee3/menu?client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&v=20150115
```

This works!